# plt.subplot2grid() command's shape dimensions----Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Basic learning of **matplotlib**, i am stuck here and don't understand the shape dimensions (3,3),(x,y),

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=3)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0), colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,2), rowspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2,0))
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [`subplot2grid`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid.html) method signature:

> *`plt.subplot2grid(shape, loc, rowspan=1, colspan=1, fig=None, **kwargs)`*

- The first param specifies the grid shape as `(rows,cols)`, so all of your subplots are on a 3x3 grid
- The second param specifies the grid location as `(row,col)` (0-indexed)
- The `rowspan` and `colspan` params specify how many rows or cols to span respectively (default 1), so `ax1` spans all 3 cols while `ax2`/`ax3` span 2 cols